# Upgrade Magento from 2.2.6 to 2.3.0 issue in core module

Tags: magento2

I am upgrading magneto version from 2.2.6 to 2.3.0 . There i am getting issue on core module `magento/module-sales`. There is error below.

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

```
- magento/module-sales 100.1.12 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -&gt; your PHP version (7.1.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/module-sales 100.1.11 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -&gt; your PHP version (7.1.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/module-sales 100.1.10 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -&gt; your PHP version (7.1.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/module-sales 100.1.9 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -&gt; your PHP version (7.1.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/module-sales 100.1.8 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -&gt; your PHP version (7.1.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/module-sales 100.1.7 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -&gt; your PHP version (7.1.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/module-sales 100.1.6 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -&gt; your PHP version (7.1.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/module-sales 100.1.5 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -&gt; your PHP version (7.1.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/module-sales 100.1.4 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -&gt; your PHP version (7.1.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/module-sales 100.1.3 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -&gt; your PHP version (7.1.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/module-sales 100.1.2 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -&gt; your PHP version (7.1.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/module-sales 100.1.1 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -&gt; your PHP version (7.1.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/module-sales 100.1.0 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -&gt; your PHP version (7.1.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/module-sales 100.1.0-rc3 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -&gt; your PHP version (7.1.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/module-sales 100.1.0-rc2 requires php ~5.5.22|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -&gt; your PHP version (7.1.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/module-sales 100.1.0-rc1 requires php ~5.5.22|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -&gt; your PHP version (7.1.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- fooman/pdfcustomiser-m2 8.0.6 requires fooman/pdfcustomiser-implementation-m2 108.3.1 -&gt; satisfiable by fooman/pdfcustomiser-implementation-m2[108.3.1].
- fooman/pdfcustomiser-m2 8.0.6 requires fooman/pdfcustomiser-implementation-m2 108.3.1 -&gt; satisfiable by fooman/pdfcustomiser-implementation-m2[108.3.1].
- fooman/pdfcustomiser-implementation-m2 108.3.1 requires magento/module-sales ^100.1.0 | ^101.0.0 -&gt; satisfiable by magento/module-sales[101.0.5, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.2.0-rc20, 101.0.0-rc21, 101.0.0-rc22, 101.0.0-rc23, 101.0.0-rc30, 100.1.8, 101.0.0, 101.0.1, 100.1.9, 100.1.10, 101.0.2, 100.1.11, 101.0.3, 101.0.4, 100.1.12, 100.1.13, 101.0.6].
- fooman/pdfcustomiser-implementation-m2 108.3.1 requires magento/module-sales ^100.1.0 | ^101.0.0 -&gt; satisfiable by magento/module-sales[101.0.5, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.2.0-rc20, 101.0.0-rc21, 101.0.0-rc22, 101.0.0-rc23, 101.0.0-rc30, 100.1.8, 101.0.0, 101.0.1, 100.1.9, 100.1.10, 101.0.2, 100.1.11, 101.0.3, 101.0.4, 100.1.12, 100.1.13, 101.0.6].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-sales[102.0.0, 101.0.5].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-sales[102.0.0, 101.0.0-rc21].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-sales[102.0.0, 101.0.0-rc22].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-sales[102.0.0, 101.0.0-rc23].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-sales[102.0.0, 101.0.0-rc30].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-sales[102.0.0, 101.0.0].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-sales[102.0.0, 101.0.1].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-sales[102.0.0, 101.0.2].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-sales[102.0.0, 101.0.3].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-sales[102.0.0, 101.0.4].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-sales[102.0.0, 101.0.5].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-sales[102.0.0, 101.0.6].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-sales[102.0.0, 100.2.0-rc20].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-sales[102.0.0, 100.1.13].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 requires magento/module-sales 102.0.0 -&gt; satisfiable by magento/module-sales[102.0.0].
- Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 -&gt; satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.0].
- Installation request for fooman/pdfcustomiser-m2 ^8.0 -&gt; satisfiable by fooman/pdfcustomiser-m2[8.0.6].</pre>
```

Please help me how can i solve it.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think so that the problem is due to your current PHP version.
Try to upgrade it with PHP 7.2 version.

Comment: Hello AbdurRahman, My php version is 7.1.20 and fresh magento 2.3.0 installed successfully even my another project also updated successfully from 2.2.5 to 2.3.0 . But in one project i am getting this core module issue.

Comment: magento/module-sales 
This seems to be a customized module (not part of it's default module)?

Answer (score 0):

the issue is because of the custom module composer.json.

Please find the keyword inside of **app** folder **5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6**

Then you can find the list of custom modules with old composer.json so after you find out you need to manually update those composer.json inside of modules folder.

For ex: **app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/composer.json**

thumps up. thanks.